# jQuery image slider with jump to slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, swiper.js

I am trying to create a content slider same as [here](http://www.net-a-porter.com/magazine/297/contents) the only thing is that they have text and images and i want only images.

Basically on first page it shows thumbnails so when you click any of them it jumps to that particular slide.

I have tried and setup the slider with swiper jquery plugin but i couldn't make it to jump to specific slide here is my code:

```
    <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/5)">
        <div class="block">
            <a href="#page6">Jumo to page 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <a href="#page2">Jumo to page 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <a href="#page3">Jumo to page 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" data-page-number="2"  class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/1)"></div>
    <div id="page3" data-page-number="3"  class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/2)"></div>
    <div id="page4" data-page-number="4"  class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/3)"></div>
    <div id="page5" data-page-number="5" class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/4)"></div>
    <div id="page6" data-page-number="6" class="swiper-slide"><h1>THIS IS PAGE 6</h1></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>

    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
</div>

<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 30,
    effect: 'fade'
});
</script>
```

Jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/yuv72u60/

Seeking help!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
            <div class="block">
                <a href="1">Jumo to page 1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <a href="2">Jumo to page 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <a href="3">Jumo to page 3</a>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".block a").click(function(){

   var index=$(this).attr('href');
    swiper.slideTo(index);
});
```

> The above mentioned are changes in have made to your JS fiddle in the `HTML` and `JS` section. `index` in the above `js` is the position of your page.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yuv72u60/2/)

> There is an API in Slider itself for your requirement I have updated your Fiddle slightly for that API to work

Comment: For some reason it works once or twice but then the slider disappears completely